# I am making an app that should read a PDF file but the path of the PDF is always getting wrong

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am selecting a PDF file below

[press here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGzP2.png)

[I am selecting the sample.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YUSi.png)

[This is the path I am getting (the one in textview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjLRZ.png)

[But I think the the path should be this one(Location)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5XY4.png)

the code that I used was using intent uri and string as seen below

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    Log.e("startSearch: ","worked");// this code ends here
```

//new function(i.e onActivityResult()) starts here

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            final Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.e("on activity result"," yes");

            //File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + File.separator + uri.getPath() +".pdf");
            final File file = new File(uri.getPath().toString());
            path.setText(file.getPath());
    }
}
```

what should I do to get the right path of the PDF?

Comment: uri.toString() is the right content scheme of your file. Dont try to get something else. You will not need the File class at all. You did not tell for what you need a 'path'. Please dont post so many links. Just tell what is going on.

Comment: i think , the thing tat i want is cleared out in the 3rd and 4th link